# Not able to see video, but video is playing

Tags: android

Am playing video using this following code. Video is playing am hearing audio. But video view showing black screen.

```
void playVideo(){
    videoPlayer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    videoPlayer.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
    videoPlayer.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    videoPlayer.requestFocus();
    videoPlayer.start();
}
```

please tell the solution.

Comment: you playing it on device or emulator?

Comment: Device.. samsung version 4.0.4